# How composite index and left join work in MySql?

Tags: mysql, database, optimization, indexing

I have two tables as per below

[image]

I have composite index on both tables as per below:

- users table has a composite index: (login_type_id, language_id, enabled, level)
- address table has a composite index: (user_id, city_id, enabled)

I would like to execute the following query

```
select * from users u
left join address adr
on u.id = adr.user_id
where u.login_type_id = 1
and u.langauge_id = 1
and u.enabled = true
and adr.city_id in (1,2,3,4,5)
and adr.enabled = true
order by u.level
```

when I execute the query, I am expecting MySQL to use the composite index on both tables since all the fields in where clauses are indexed. But MySql uses the address table as base and only used the primary key of users to join.

Does MySql ignore a composite index when joining two tables?

Can you guys give me an idea of why MySql does not use composite index on both tables?

To make the query fastest, which fields should I create indexes on, please?

Thank you.

Explain SQL
[image]

Please note that actual database is different from the database in the question but the relationship and index are the same.

Comment: might be easier if you include the `EXPLAIN {query}` info. Which MySQL version?

Comment: @danblack hellp danblack, thank you very much for your comment, I have just uploaded the result of MySql explain of my query. I am using Mysql version 8.0.19.

Comment: 1) The order by on level (not covered by index) may be problematic, view the plan with it omitted; 2) Include the ID in the index (covered) so the join can be done without a primary read-back.

Comment: MySQL-8.0.verynew has [EXPLAIN ANALYZE {query}](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html) that shows more information. Also from your `EXPLAIN`, your dataset seems to be only 3 rows. You need a lot bigger sample if you want to be more sure as to what's a standard MySQL query plan given these indexes.

Comment: *I have composite index on both tables as per below* What reason caused you to make these indices?

Comment: @danblack thank you the EXPLAIN ANALYZE is very useful. I have not known this. and yes sure, I will add more test rows and test it again. but can you please give a general idea of how MySql uses composite key with left join? and any suggestion for indexing for those two tables please?

Comment: @Akina I thought MySql would use those composite keys because I have those fields in "where" clause indexed in the "composite indices". But it does not... just want to know how MySql actually uses a composite index with left join. and any better suggestion to index those fields to speed up my query.

Comment: Different data can generate different results. Get more data there before you make too many design decisions.

Comment: @danblack yes that's right but all the fields indexed are either integer or boolean. so there would not be a huge difference between "different data", I guess.

Comment: please stop guessing. The tables are "sampled" for a number of pages and those sample pages are matched against the search criteria to see what its likely to incude the lower query cost.

Comment: *I thought MySql would use those composite keys because I have those fields in "where" clause indexed in the "composite indices".* Their expressions MUST start with the field used fro joining! the fields used in WHERE must be the rest of index expression.

Comment: Never use `SELECT *`. And never use `LEFT JOIN` if what you actually want is an `INNER JOIN`

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table; there are other important details.

Comment: "how MySql uses composite key with left join" -- As Strawberry points out, it is _not_ a `LEFT JOIN`.  This is because of requirements on `adr` specified in the `WHERE` clause.  The Optimizer is smart enough to figure that out -- as seen by which table it started with (see the `EXPLAIN`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- When you have constraints (see `WHERE`) on the 'right' table of a `LEFT JOIN`; the Optimizer will turn it into a regular `JOIN`.  This allows it to rearrange the tables.
- The `PRIMARY KEY` is usually the optimal way to `JOIN` to a table.
- A "covering" `INDEX` is one that has *all* the columns needed for the query.  Since you specified `SELECT *`, you are asking for `full_name`, which is missing from your index, therefore it is not "covering".
- The order of the columns in an index *may* be very important.  (But not in your example.)  This *could* lead to not using a composite index, and perhaps even a covering index.
- Generally, it is best to put columns tested by `=` first in a composite index.
- If it is not a covering index, the Optimizer will stop at the first "range" column in a composite index.  (Not relevant in your example.)
- `IN(1,2,3,4)` might be optimized like `=` or like a range, depending on the phase of the moon.
- Cardinality of the *components* of a composite index does not matter when arranging the columns.
- If the Optimizer thinks that it needs to touch more than something like 20% of an index, it will shun the index and use a table scan.

More:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql and http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index1